# How to install smbus to virtualenv?

Tags: python, i2c

How to setup python-smbus in the virtual env? Pip does not find any appropriate package. Is there a way to make main python installation's libraries visible to virtual env?

Answer (score 6):

The various releases are listed here the Debian Wheezy [python-smbus](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-smbus) page.

I assume you can just install via apt-get, although I believe you need to i2c tools package as well:

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
sudo apt-get install python-smbus
```

When you create your virtual environment you should be able to inherit the system site packages using the --system-site-packages flag for example:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages my_env
```

You can read more at the [virtualenv.org](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) website.

Incase I misunderstood your question...

If you are asking how to install into your virtual environment from a package server that is pip compatible and contains the package (python-smbus) you can update your pip.conf file to include it.

Navigate to the .pip directory under your users root folder.
Then edit the pip.conf file, for example:

```
vim /home/pi/.pip/pip.conf
```

You can then add an additional package repository in here:

```
[global]
index-url = path/to/package/server
```

Installing it in your virtual environment is then as easy as:

```
./bin/pip install <package>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'd first opt for inheriting system packages. Wonder if I could modify existing virtual environment to inherit them, but I will try it out.

Comment: There is no /.pip/ in /home/pi/. What now?

Comment: One reason for setting up a virtualenv, is to have an isolated environment owned by an isolated user who comes to your (web) appllication from outside. That user is typically not a sudoer. So `sudo apt-get install` won't work. 
Better answers for that use case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079607/make-virtualenv-inherit-specific-packages-from-your-global-site-packages) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371136/revert-the-no-site-packages-option-with-virtualenv).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `smbus2` instead.  It is a pure python replacement you can just install with `pip` as normal.  Works fine for me.
https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/